# Does water in the drain follow the distance-squared rule of force?

Tags: astronomy, home-experiment

When I shower I notice that the soapy water spinning around the drain often takes the form of a spinning galaxy, complete with spiral arms. Does this indicate that the water's speed around the drain is inversely proportional to the square of its distance from the drain? Actually, I have heard that spinning galaxies themselves don't follow this rule, hence the discovery of dark matter, so does the spinning water follow whatever rule that the spinning stars do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the free (irrotational) vortex section of the [Wikipedia article on vortices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vortex#Free_.28irrotational.29_vortex). The velocity varies linearly with distance not as the square of the distance.

Comment: Thank you John. Linear variation sounds to me as though the soap is spinning as a solid mass, which in retrospect does seem to be the case as I don't notice the shape changing as it spins. How then do the spiral arms form?

Comment: When I shower this morning I will make a point of studying the water drainage :-)

Comment: Looking at the spinning soap this morning, in fact the center was spinning (angularly) faster than the outer edges. I don't have a way of measuring the linear velocity at each distance, but it certainly wasn't spinning as a solid body!